# how to count duplicates in a list of tuples and append it as a new value

Tags: python, list, scripting

```
output = [('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO'),('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO'),('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO'),('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO'),('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO'),('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO')]
```

so here there are total of 6 set of `('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO')` in this above list

so Im expecting an output like this ~

expected_output = `[('studentA','ISDF',6), ('studentB','CSE',6),('studentC','BIO',6)]`

The format should be `[('student', 'department', total count)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
sorted([tuple(list(item)+[output.count(item)]) for item in set(output)])
```

or

```
sorted([item+(output.count(item),) for item in set(output)])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

output = [('studentA', 'ISDF'), ('studentB', 'CSE'), ('studentC', 'BIO'),
          ('studentA', 'ISDF'), ('studentB', 'CSE'), ('studentC', 'BIO'),
          ('studentA', 'ISDF'), ('studentB', 'CSE'), ('studentC', 'BIO'),
          ('studentA', 'ISDF'), ('studentB', 'CSE'), ('studentC', 'BIO'),
          ('studentA', 'ISDF'), ('studentB', 'CSE'), ('studentC', 'BIO'),
          ('studentA', 'ISDF'), ('studentB', 'CSE'), ('studentC', 'BIO')]

counts = Counter(output)
print(counts)
print([k + (v, ) for k, v in counts.items()])
```

Out:

```
Counter({('studentA', 'ISDF'): 6, ('studentB', 'CSE'): 6, ('studentC', 'BIO'): 6})
[('studentA', 'ISDF', 6), ('studentB', 'CSE', 6), ('studentC', 'BIO', 6)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from collections and a list comprehension

```py
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(output)
exp_output = [(key[0], key[1], value) for key, value in count.items()]
print(exp_output)
```

---

```
[('studentA', 'ISDF', 6), ('studentB', 'CSE', 6), ('studentC', 'BIO', 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = [('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO'), 
    ('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO'), 
    ('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO'), 
    ('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO'), 
    ('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO'), 
    ('studentA','ISDF'), ('studentB','CSE'),('studentC','BIO')]
keys = list(set(output))
[k + (output.count(k),) for k in keys]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using collection.Counter is ideal for this. However, if for some reason you want to avoid an import you could do it like this:

```
d = dict()

for e in output:
    d[e] = d.get(e, 0) + 1

print([(a, b, v) for (a, b), v in d.items()])
```

**Output:**

```
[('studentA', 'ISDF', 6), ('studentB', 'CSE', 6), ('studentC', 'BIO', 6)]
```